# DWORD casting to float after a simple swap?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, swap, dword

I want to swap my float exemple: 14 D7 65 01 ----> 65 01 14 D7

The swap is easy to do. I work on a DWORD, I made my swap and then I cast my DWORD variable to float. The problem I have is that the float value is wrong. 
I am sure that The DWORD swap is ok and well done. I think that the cast is made badly.
Any help is more than welcome! Thank you in advance!

Here is the core of the code:

```
    DWORD value = 0x713D2242; 
    value =(LOWORD(value)<<16)+ HIWORD (value); 
    float fvalue = (float)value;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a union, e.g.:

```
union
{
    DWORD i;
    float f;
} u;

DWORD value = 0x713D2242; 
u.i = (LOWORD(value) << 16) + HIWORD(value); 
float fvalue = u.f;
```

Answer (score 5):

I donot know why but I found a solution from a book which casting a float number to a DWORD number:

```
float f = ...;
DOWRD dw;
dw = *((DWORD*)&F);
```